# Creating a Content Type using the REST API

Tags: rest, content-type

I am wondering if there is a way that I can use the REST API to create a content type in SharePoint online. I am trying to do this from a Node.js application that is sat inside an Azure function.

I have managed to get all the authentication keys that I am ever going to need I believe but I cannot find anyway to do it. Any help would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this (note I'm using [`sp-request`](https://github.com/s-KaiNet/sp-request))

```js
  spr.requestDigest('https://sp2013dev/sites/dev')
  .then(function (digest) {
    return spr.post('https://sp2013dev/sites/dev/_api/web/contenttypes', {
      body: {
            '__metadata': {'type': 'SP.ContentType'},
           'Description': 'TestDesc',
           'Name': 'ContentType New',
           'Group': 'Custom Group',        
            'Id':{
                '__metadata':{
                    'type':'SP.ContentTypeId'
                },
                'StringValue':'0x01978768sdfs456df'
            }
      },
      headers: {
        'X-RequestDigest': digest
      }
    });
  })
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log('Created!');
  })
  .catch(function (err) {
      console.log(err.message);
  });
```

**UPD**
BTW, I recommend you to try [pnp-js-core](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-JS-Core) with nodejs. Recently I created a demo repository with setup required in order to use pnp-js-core from nodejs: [node-pnpjs-sample](https://github.com/s-KaiNet/node-pnpjs-sample).
With `pnp-js-core` you can simply write:

```
let web: pnp.Web = new pnp.Web(settings.siteUrl);
web.contentTypes.add('ct id', 'name', 'description')
.then(() => {
    console.log('created!');
});
```

Comment: I have been using sp-request and it is really good! With this code here I get a 500 error.

Comment: Any error messages?

Comment: 2016-11-11T15:36:14.886 { StatusCodeError: 500 - {"error":{"code":"183, Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"A duplicate content type \"ContentType New\" was found."}}}

This makes me think it worked but isn't appearing in SharePoint UI

Comment: That's mean you already created content type with following name.